# Calculating variance of an Ornstein Uhlenbeck process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I have the following process

$$dX_t = (b-aX_t)dt + dW_t$$
$$X_0 = x_0$$
with $a,b,x_0$ constants, and I wish to calculate the variance. (I have already solved for the process and for the expected value). To find $E(X^2)$, my idea was to use to set $Z_t = X_t^2$, apply Itos lemma and take expectations on each side. That is
$$dZ_t = 2X_tdX + 2(dX)^2$$
$$= 2X_t(b-aX_t)dt +2X_tdW_t+2dt$$
Integrating from $0$ to $t$ and taking expectations
$$E(Z_t) = x_0^2 +2b\int_0^tE(X_s)ds-2a\int_0^tZ_sds + 2t$$
where $E(X_t) = e^{-at}(x_0 - \frac{b}{a})+\frac{b}{a}$.

I have no idea how to solve the above equation. Is there another way to calculate this variance that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation gets a little bit easier if you use Itô's formula to calculate $\mathbb{E}((X_t-\mathbb{E}(X_t))^2)$ instead of $\mathbb{E}(X_t^2)$.

Set $\mu_t := \mathbb{E}(X_t) = e^{-at} \left( x_0- \frac{b}{a} \right) + \frac{b}{a}$. Applying Itô's formula to

$$Y_t := (X_t-\mu_t)^2$$

gives

$$dY_t = 2 (X_t-\mu_t)(b-a X_t-\mu'(t)) + 2 (X_t-\mu_t) \, dW_t + 2 dt,$$

and this implies

$$\mathbb{E}(Y_t^2) = 2t -2a \int_0^t \mathbb{E}(Y_s) \, ds.$$

This means that $f(t) := \mathbb{E}(Y_t^2)$ is a solution to the ordinary differential equation

$$f'(t) = 2 - 2a f(t) \qquad f(0)=0.$$

Solve it...

Comment: Thank you! I suspected that there was an easier way to approach this.

Comment: @Chris You are welcome.

Comment: @saz Is the Ito's formula you are applying this one: $f(W_{t})-f(W_{0}) = \int^{t}_{0} f'(W_{s})dW_{s} +\frac{1}{2}\int^{t}_{0}f''(W_{s})ds$? The $f$ here is just a generic $C^{2}$ function. If so, I'm having trouble seeing the application of it.

Comment: @user135520 Well, no, I used Itô's formula for Itô processes, see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma#It%C3%B4_drift-diffusion_processes_(due_to:_Kunita%E2%80%93Watanabe))

Comment: Couldn't we just compute the variance directly using Ito's Isometry?